# How exactly does NITZ work?

Tags: clock, date-and-time

My understanding is that phones have an internal RTC (real-time clock) which is regularly synchronized, using NITZ (default) and NTP when the phone is connected to internet.

Carriers can broadcast a special signal encoding UTC time information (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Timezone and [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)) with an accuracy in the order of minutes.

I read the [3GPP specification](https://portal.3gpp.org/desktopmodules/Specifications/SpecificationDetails.aspx?specificationId=576) and found when time information can be transferred from the serving [PLMN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_land_mobile_network) to the Mobile Station ([MS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_station)) / User equipment ([UE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_equipment)) :

> 1. Upon registering on the network.
> 2. When the MS geographically relocates to a different Local Time Zone.
> 3. When the network changes its Local Time Zone, e.g. between summer and winter time.
> 4. When the network changes its identity.
> 5. At any time during a signalling connection with mobile station.

*Automatic date and time* needs to be enabled in the phone settings to either use NITZ or NTP. **Technically a SIM card is not required right?** If so, this should work in airplane mode but I didn't manage to trigger a time update after having manually changed the time.

I think I don't understand how it works in practice.

- **When does this trigger ? How does the cell tower know 2) 3)?**
- **If it periodically broadcasts time information to every phones in the area then what's the meaning of these 5 points?**
- **What does 1) 4) and 5) mean in concrete terms?**

Regarding NTP, it is a lot simpler. Android will synchronize with a NTP server if there hasn't been any NITZ update from the carrier ever since 24H. The default NTP server is `time.android.com` (Google server) but I guess manufacturers may change this to use their own. (source: [config.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml#2270))

Comment: `Technically a SIM card is not required right?` But some radio connectivity should be as otherwise the device is isolated. Related search gave me this: https://github.com/ghbolivar/android-on-freerunner/issues/67